# How Can I Send "Voice" Commands To My Personal Alexa Device Via Python Code?

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

I want to send "voice" commands to my home alexa device to do, well, anything that I "ask" it to.

So I want to interact with my Alexa device via python. I feel like I'm going around in circles trying to get this to work. I got it at one point using "gTTS" to convert my text to an audio file and attempt to send that audio file to an alexa endpoint but it also doesn't do anything. I have even created a "product" and gotten my product id, client id, secret id, and refresh token and have been attempting to use those.

Is this possible? I need some hope here. I'm feeling a little down like this isn't possible.

If it is possible am I going down the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Your home device is only meant to take commands via the mic. You could create a DIY hardware or software device that consumes the Alexa Voice Service and feed audio to it.

Comment: When developing an Alexa skill you're able to send text to the Alexa because it converts the text to an audio file and feeds it to Alexa that interprets it. I figured I should be able to do the same things via code. It's looking like that isn't the case and I might have to go with a custom hardware solution like you suggest.

Comment: "you're able to send text to the Alexa because it converts the text to an audio file and feeds it to Alexa that interprets it" - Are you talking about in the testing simulator in the Developer Console?

Comment: Ya, that's what I was referreing to.

Comment: The simulator is basically an Alexa Voice Service software device built into the web site. Here's the docs on the API. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-voice-service/api-overview.html and here's a promising looking (not officially blessed and haven't tried it myself) python project... https://github.com/respeaker/avs

Comment: Talking from the future.. did you manage to do that project? I'm now attempting to do it and I followed your steps with no success. @wesleywh

Comment: Nope. Gave up on the project.